# lisp - single quote string check in list

Tags: lisp

I am thinking about this.
How can I check single quote string in list? (not double quote string)
Function stringp, typecase, and so on.. is Only handle double quotes.

I want make (f '((3 a) (2 b) (1 c))) should return six.
Non-integer should be ignore.

I tried this code.

```
(defun f (lst)
              (typecase lst
              (integer (+ (f (first lst)) (f (rest lst))))
              (list 0))
              )
```

I need to check the single-quoted string in the list.
However, stringp, typecase it doesn't work as I want.

what should I do solve this problem?

Comment: This is a good Lisp introduction: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/   It will also explain symbols and how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `'((3 a) (2 b) (1 c))`, there are **no string**: no single-quoted string (no such thing in Lisp), no double-quoted strings. You have this value:

```
(quote ((3 a) (2 b) (1 c)))
```

[`QUOTE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_quote.htm) is a **special operator**, which prevents the evaluation of its subform. What is inside the quote is literal, constant data, that is read but not evaluated.

Here, you have a **list** of lists, each of them containing a **number** in the first position, and a **symbol** as the second element. In particular, there is no string.

A symbol is an object which has a name (a string). Each occurrence of the same symbol `x` refers to the same object<sup>**1**</sup>. Here below, all the `x` points to the same symbol:

```
((3 x) (2 x) (1 x))
```

In your code, you only need to check whether there is an integer and use zero for anything else: floats, strings, symbols, vectors, hash-tables, CLOS instances, ....

A big problem in your code is that you check if the variable `list` (a bad name, since you are not sure if it is a list) is an *integer*, but then you proceed to take the *first* and *rest* of this integer: that is guaranteed to fail!

```
(defun f (form)
  (typecase form

    ;; cons cell: recurse
    (cons (+ (f (first form))
             (f (rest form))))

    ;; integer: form is the value
    (integer form)

    ;; anything else: zero
    (t 0)))
```

If your data always follow the same pattern (a list of couples with one number, one symbol), you can simply iterate over each pair and sum the number:

```
(loop for (number symbol) in list sum number)
```

---

**1.** In the same [package](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html), if you don't *unintern* the symbol.